# pgfplotstable and longtable with caption is shown multiple times in tableslist

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

I'm visualizing a csv file using pgfplotstable and longtable as followed:

```
\newcommand{\powerTable}[3]{
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        col sep = comma,
        skip rows between index={0}{#2},
        skip rows between index={#3}{1000000000},
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
        % packo id,N,Packomania Radius,,id,circlecount,Radius,time (ns),overlap (square units),nancount,Time,,Difference,% Increase
        columns={{N},{ratio},{Radius},{Difference},{Increase},{Time}},
        every head row/.style={before row=\caption{#1}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        column type={l}, %default
        columns/{N}/.style={column type={c}},
        columns/{ratio}/.style={column name={Beste radius}},
        columns/{Radius}/.style={column name={Radius}},
        columns/{Difference}/.style={column name={Vergroting}},
        columns/{Increase}/.style={column type={c}, column name={Vergroting (\%)}},
        columns/{Time}/.style={column name={Tijd}},
    ]{csv/Power Packomania Problems Comparison.csv}
}
```

I added a caption that shows up on every page. However it also shows up multiple times in my `\listoftables`. I'm assuming it's because pgfplotstable actually generates duplicates of the caption for every page. But how can I make it so it only shows up once in the list of tables?

Thanks!

After a lot of trying out different stuff, I found this to work:

```
\newcommand{\powerTable}[3]{
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        col sep = comma,
        skip rows between index={0}{#2},
        skip rows between index={#3}{1000000000},
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
        % packo id,N,Packomania Radius,,id,circlecount,Radius,time (ns),overlap (square units),nancount,Time,,Difference,% Increase
        columns={{N},{ratio},{Radius},{Difference},{Increase},{Time}},
        every head row/.style={before row=\caption[]{#1}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        every first row/.style={before row=\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}\caption[#1]{}\\[-23pt]},
        column type={l}, %default
        columns/{N}/.style={column type={c}},
        columns/{ratio}/.style={column name={Beste radius}},
        columns/{Radius}/.style={column name={Radius}},
        columns/{Difference}/.style={column name={Vergroting}},
        columns/{Increase}/.style={column type={c}, column name={Vergroting (\%)}},
        columns/{Time}/.style={column name={Tijd}},
    ]{csv/Power Packomania Problems Comparison.csv}
}
```

Notice the use of `\\[-23pt]` in the style of every first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\powerTable}[3]{
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        col sep = comma,
        skip rows between index={0}{#2},
        skip rows between index={#3}{1000000000},
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
        % packo id,N,Packomania Radius,,id,circlecount,Radius,time (ns),overlap (square units),nancount,Time,,Difference,% Increase
        columns={{N},{ratio},{Radius},{Difference},{Increase},{Time}},
        every head row/.style={before row=\caption[]{#1}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
        every last row/.style={after row=\caption{#1}\bottomrule},
        column type={l}, %default
        columns/{N}/.style={column type={c}},
        columns/{ratio}/.style={column name={Beste radius}},
        columns/{Radius}/.style={column name={Radius}},
        columns/{Difference}/.style={column name={Vergroting}},
        columns/{Increase}/.style={column type={c}, column name={Vergroting (\%)}},
        columns/{Time}/.style={column name={Tijd}},
    ]{csv/Power Packomania Problems Comparison.csv}
}
```

if you use the captioncommand on every page with \caption[]{#1} no entry in lot will be made. Only at the last row it will be done. therefor the tablelist list the table on the last page where the table is located.

I do not know for sure, if this solve the problem because you did not provide a Minimal Working Example. It is only a solution because of knowledge, untested.

Comment: @egreg you are right. Answer was edit just a few minutes ago.

Comment: This almost worked! I had to change this line `every last row/.style={after row=\caption{#1}\\\bottomrule},` (note the additional \\ before bottomrule). However, is it possible to get the page number to be the first page of the table?

Comment: I tried using 
        `every head row/.style={before row=\caption[]{#1}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        every first row/.style={before row=\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}\caption[#1]{}\\}` which almost works, only now I get an extra white space before the first row. But if I remove the \\ it won't build.

Comment: @TheOddler try  \newtabularline instead of \\ (maybe this helps)

Comment: It is supposed to be `\tabularnewline`, but it gives the same problem. And using `\kill` does hide the row, but then the table doesn't shown in the lot anymore...

Comment: Ok, what worked is using `\\[-25pt]`. This moved the row slightly up (25 points), so counteracts the extra blank row. It's a bit of a hack, but works very nicely, even if I only show part of the rows. I have accepted your answer because you helped me get there. Thanks!